# Using javascript client-side, how can I display a "virtual folder" (= a coherent collection of html,img,js with relative paths)?

Tags: javascript, virtual-file

I want to display autonomous "sites" on a html page (Say "root").
Those "sites" contain a landing page : index.html and a collection of *.css, *.js,*.png)
By autonomous, I mean those sites does not have external dependencies and all paths are relative = you can copy them in any directory or host them anywhere and they'll work.
Those sites are zipped in a archive that contains all necessary files.
Say I got no problem with the download and got all the files in memory (as path/uint8 array)

How could I display the site in a safe way ?
I can parse the index.html, change all the src and href for data-url of the original files and load it in an iframe.
It works rather well but it breaks where there are scripts like this

```
if (extension == "pdf")
 img.src = "images/thumb-pdf.png"
```

Is there any way to control the url served by the iframe?
Some kind of proxy?
Can I intercept "images/thumb-pdf.png" to serve MemoryCacheOfAllFiles["images/thumb-pdf.png"].toDataURL() instead ?

PS: Of course I got no control on those sites and I can't store them on server (it would be to easy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proxy are possible in javascript one got to use a [worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker) and listen for the "fetch" event to push the virtual content.

html pushed in iframe:

```
...
navigator.serviceWorker.register('worker.js').then(function() {
    logInstall('Installing...');
  })
...
```

worker.js:

```
...
self.onfetch = function(event) {
  var cached = (mycache[event.request.url]); // do we have content
  if (cached)
    event.respondWith(new Response(cached.content,{
      headers:{"Content-Type",cached.mimetype}
    }
  else
    event.respondWith(fetch(event.request));
}
...
```

Full code by mozilla to unzip and serve content
https://serviceworke.rs/cache-from-zip.html